# $G-F$ disconnected iff $F\cap E(T)\neq \emptyset$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a undirected connected graph and $F\subseteq E$. Show that $G-F$ is disconnected iff for every spanning tree $T=(V,E(T))$ of $G$ we have $F\cap E(T)\neq\emptyset$.
I thought about using the fact that a graph is connected if one only if there is a spanning tree, but I didn't get any further with that.

Comment: Here we have two statements:
(1) If $F\cap E(T)\neq\varnothing$ for every spanning tree $T$, then the graph $G-F$ is disconnected.
(2) If $G-F$ is disconnected, then for any spanning tree $T$ we have $F\cap E(T)\neq\varnothing$.
Both can be easily proved from the contrary.

Answer (score 1):

If $F \cap E(T) \ne \varnothing$  for every spanning tree $T$, then the graph $G - F$ is disconnected, because it doesn't contain any spanning tree. If $G - F$ is disconnected, then for any spanning tree $T$ of the graph $G$ we have $F \cap E(T) \ne \varnothing$, because otherwise $G - F$ would have a spanning tree.